# MPLab X IPE won't start

Tags: microchip, mplab

I just installed MPLab X 3.61. When I try to run the IPE the splash screen displays, then goes away, then nothing else. I am running Windows 10 . Microchip has been no help. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Dennis

Comment: I just installed 3.65 after doing a complete uninstall of 3.61. I still have the same issue. The IPE shows the splash screen and then goes away, with no error messages. Does anyone have any ideas what else I can try to fix this issue? I have had a case in at MicroChip since May and they have been no help at all. This is on a Windows 10 system.

Answer (score 0):

I was with the same problem. Today I updated the NVidia driver to play a game and it solved the problem with the MPLAB X.